# Software to determine optimal hardware components for a user's requirements of a PC

Tags: windows, hardware

It is hard deciding what PC components to use to build a balanced system, given ideas of what it will be used for and what performance is desired. At least, without going overboard.

Is there software that can help with this? Conceivably it could hold a database of parts: motherboards, processors, RAM, HDDs, a database of software: games, OS's, professional s/w, etc, and then query the user on requirements like screen resolution and desired fps, types and number of applications open simultaneously, desired boot up time, cost of the hardware, etc. And then have a way of allowing the user to mix and match parts (or ones with equivalent specs if not in the database) to find a solution that gives best tradeoffs between cost and performance?

Specifically, for example, I want a PC that gives lightning fast application loading times, and other tasks which tend to max out only a single core of the CPU and/or the HDDs read capacity (guessing: it might be the motherboard). But deciding what parts to use is pretty hit and miss / guesswork.

Perhaps a second-best solution would be software that takes the pain out of determining the bottlenecks in an existing PC when certain tasks are executed and makes it a no-brainer to decide which component(s) to upgrade?

Note: The machine I will build would run windows

Comment: Any OS requirement?

Comment: The machine I will build would run windows but I could run the app on Ubuntu

Comment: Can the software run on Windows or does it have to run on Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry - I meant windows for both if possible

Comment: Great, I've edited your question including what you have said, please read it over verifying everything is correctly stated

Answer (score 1):

What you desire seems like it would need a certain amount of heuristics, or, knowledge based support.  I’m not sure thats possible given all of the possibilities.  Having said that, I think the next best thing would be something like [PcPartPicker](https://pcpartpicker.com/).  At a minimum, you’ll have more control over the build especially in terms of budget.  Additionally, PcPartPicker provides a user forum to ask for and share information about pc builds.